# Background property being stripped out? NOT overridden

Tags: css, sharepoint

I'm not sure if this is a Sharepoint issue or if something strange has been added to this site, but I've looked searched trying to find someone with the same issue to no avail...

I'm simply adding a class to `<a>` tags to add a pdf icon. The padding and margins get added, but the background property is completely stripped out, it is not simply being overwritten... It's as if I never added the background property. When I go into firebug and add the background in it works fine though.

Has anyone had this issue with sharepoint? I've never seen this issue before but I've never used sharepoint either...

```
a.link-pdf-icon {
    background: url('../images/pdf-icon-12x12.png') transparent no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-left:14px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

Used with single quotes, double quotes and no quotes... Also tried with !important, no difference.

Comment: I would guess you entered invalid background value. You need to share your code with us to reproduce and solve the problem.

Comment: Code added, but it's extremely basic... Not making sense to me why it's being stripped out, if it was being overridden atleast I'd be able to track it down.

Comment: What happens if you split the background to multiple properties, like `background-image: url(...); background-color: transparent; background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: background-image: is missing... Forget it, i'm just going to use the class to push the icons into the <a> with js. Not worth it to track down what this site is doing just to put an icon on a link haha I just thought maybe there was a bug in sharepoint or something.

Comment: this could help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68286/impossible-to-set-background-image-of-a-div-for-sharepoint-online

Comment: Looks like that one was just being overwritten by sharepoint... But problem solved i just used js works like a charm. Thanks Aziz

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `background` value is invalid.

> `background: url('../images/pdf-icon-12x12.png') transparent no-repeat 0 0;`

`0 0` is not a valid value for [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position).

You could use `0px 0px` or `0% 0%` instead.